# Specific Box shadow to button in css

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a button like this one in the pic

[image]

But what I'm getting is this

[image]

As you can see, the shadow is different.

The property I'm using is a basic box-shadow.

```
.boton{
    width: 30%;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #000;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

How can I get a style like in the second image

Comment: To be clear what's the difference? What makes the second image wrong? Please [edit] you're question to clearly explain the problem you're seeing.

Comment: You can read up about the box-shadow properties here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/css/box-shadow In particular look at the settings for blur and spread radius.

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR:**

try to use change the third param to `0px` or `0`

so it will be something like this: `box-shadow: 2px 2px 0 #000;`

---

### why "0"?

the `box-shadow` css property can have some parameters,

 the parameters need to have a space between.

> offset-x | offset-y | blur-radius | color
>
>                                   ⬆️⬆️⬆️

and in your case the 3° parameter is the **blur-radius**, so by just resetting the blur you solved the problem.

---

**Docs:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/css/box-shadow

---

#### Example:

the interesting about this, is you can animate it on hover (see example below)

[image]

```css
.boton {
  width: 30%;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 0 #000; /* what I changed in your code */
  cursor: pointer;
  
  /* this lines below this line are not important, you can delete them if you want to */
  transition: 0.5s;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 5px;
}

.boton:hover {
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 0 #000;
}
```

```html
<button class="boton">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbhzF.png" height="20" alt="google logo" />
  <span>hello world</span>
</button>
```